# how can define Dbset<class> for parameter method

Tags: c#, code-first

method is:

```
public UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
    public ActionResult _Create(MyClass_View content)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)            
        {
            MyClass Home = new MyClass();
            Mapper.Map(content, Home);
            if (content.Id <= 0)                
                db.MyClasses.Add(Home);                                    
            else                
                db.Entry(Home).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("Ok");
        }
        return PartialView(content);
    }
```

but I want change method by tow parametrs whit db.MyClasses is param for use this method by db.MyClass1 or db.MyClass2
db.MyClasses is :

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
 public Dbset<MyClass> MyClasses {get; set;}
 public Dbset<MyClass> MyClasses1 {get; set;}
 public Dbset<MyClass> MyClasses2 {get; set;}
}
```

for example method may be :

```
    public ActionResult _Create(MyClass_View content, XXX c)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)            
        {
            MyClass Home = new MyClass();
            Mapper.Map(content, Home);
            if (content.Id <= 0)                
                c.Add(Home);                                    
            else                
                db.Entry(Home).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("Ok");
        }
        return PartialView(content);
    }
```

I don't know XXX type ?
thanks for answer

Comment: The parameter would be `DbSet<MyClass>`, but it will always be null if invoked from the MVC pipeline, originating from a request.

Comment: I want call method by  dbSet<MyClass1> or DbSet<MyClass2> !